# Reduce curveness of Bézier curve algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to make my graph like [like they are with chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org).

In the image bellow, the red dots are the data points, the green graph is the graph we get if we connect all the red dots. The black line is the result of the graph after applying the Bézier curve algorithm.

[image]

**Question**: How to reduce the curveness of the black line and make my graph like in chartjs?

**edit:** I am trying to create a cool looking graph. I don't want the graph to look like the green line because it's not pretty. I also don't want the graph to look like the black line because it loses all the details. I want my graph to be like chartjs. Antialias is another story and not asked here.

Comment: it is all about `not connecting the dots`, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing

Comment: Can you describe your problem in a less "guess what I mean" way? What do you mean by "reducing curveness"? Can you provide an image of what you want to have instead of what you got?

Comment: *How* are you doing this - what does your code look like?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: I am trying to create a cool looking graph. I don't want the graph to look like the green line because it's not pretty. I also don't want the graph to look like the black line because it loses all the details. I want my graph to be like chartjs. Antialias is another story and not asked here.

Comment: @0x90: out of those algorithms, which one fits my needs?

Comment: So you want a curve that moves through all the red points, but is not angular, ie. it will have smooth turns, but still go through all the red points? That is called a spline.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error: the green line is simply made by connecting the dots. The black line is based on the code provided here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25237/Bezier-Curves-Made-Simple

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: exactly this. Can you please provide more information?

Comment: No, sorry I can't, I don't have much experience in this area, which is why I did not provide this as an answer. The wikipedia article - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics) - has some information, but I can't give you any better specifics.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: NP, hope it will be of help.

Comment: Check out http://www.particleincell.com/blog/2012/bezier-splines/. The interactive demo is particularly interesting.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: thanks a lot, it seems exactly what I am looking for. I tried it, and after converting the js to c++ I didn't got an expected result and the graph lines are both inaccurate and very little curvy. I just got all the points and I send them to the function. Then the function returned 2x the number of input points. Maybe I should send point 1, 2, 3 and 4 and then 4, 5, 6, 7 and then 7, 8, 9, 10 etc or the logic is completely different? I will try to tidy my messy code so I can post it. I am amazed this problem is not simple... maybe maths are important I guess... :/

Comment: That's the nature of Bezier curves, between every two points there are two additional points that control the curvature without being on the curve itself. If you're plotting them all as straight line segments it won't look right. You need to plot them with special Bezier rendering code.